# Authenticating with Devise in a Facebook Canvas

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I am creating a Canvas Facebook application. In this canvas i want to show a built with rails (v.3.2.8) application, which authentication part is managed by Devise 2.1.2. I followed the Facebook documentation on Server side Authentication.

My canvas url is a controller action which do the following :
 - get the facebook signed_request, decode it, redirect to the facebook authorization request page
 - once the user authorized the application, and the facebook token is sent back to my canvas url, I fetch the User infos, save them in my User model and sign in the user with devise.

My problem is : even after i signed in the user, what i see in the canvas chrome is signed-out page only. Even if the user is correctly saved in the DB, the sign_in step doesn't work, when i check the session, it is empty ?

Can anyone help me on this please ? Thanks. Here is the code of the canvas action :

```
def canvas
    @encoded_sig, @payload = params[:signed_request].split('.')
    @payload += '=' * (4 - @payload.size.modulo(4))
    # Decode the signed_request parameter
    @signature = Base64.decode64(@encoded_sig)
    @datas = JSON.parse(Base64.decode64(@payload))
    # TODO Check Encoding Algorithm
    # TODO Check Signature
    if( !@datas.has_key?("user_id") && !@datas.has_key?("oauth_token") )
      @oauth_url = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/?client_id=#{@facebook_config[:app_id]}&redirect_uri=#{@facebook_config[:canvas_page_url]}&scope=email,user_location,user_relationships"
      # render
    else
      user_datas = FbGraph::User.me(@datas["oauth_token"]).fetch
      @user = User.find_by_email(user_datas.email)
      if @user.nil?
        @user = User.new(first_name: user_datas.first_name, last_name: user_datas.last_name, email: user_datas.email , password: SecureRandom.hex(10), terms: true, fb_uid: user_datas.raw_attributes[:id], access_token: @datas["oauth_token"])
        @user.save!
        @user.confirm!
        @user.create_coachee_profile(name: user_datas.name, gender: user_datas.gender, location: '', language: user_datas.locale, relationship_status: user_datas.relationship_status, user_id: @user.id)
        sign_in(:user, @user)
        redirect_to user_coachee_profile_url(current_user.id)
      else
        sign_in(:user, @user)
        redirect_to root_url
      end
    end
  end
```